# When to reset index? loc vs iloc for gaps in index? Best practices?

Tags: python, pandas

I discovered a very subtle bug in my code. I frequently delete rows from a dataframe in my analysis. Because this will leave gaps in the index, I try to end all functions by resetting the index at the end with

```
df0 = df0.reset_index (drop = True)
```

Then I continue in the next function with

```
for row in xrange (df0.shape [0]):
    print df0.loc [row]
    print df0.iloc [row]
```

However, if I dont reset the index correctly, the first row might have an index of 192. The index of 192 is not the same as the row number of 0. This leads to the problem that df0.loc[row] accesses the row with index 0, and df0.iloc[row] are accessing the row with index 192. This has caused a very strange bug, in that I try to update row 0, but index 192 gets updated instead. Or vice versa.

But in reality, I dont use any df0.loc() or df0.iloc() functions because they are too slow. My code is riddled with df0.get_value(...) and df0.set_value(...) functions because they are the fastest functions when accessing values.

And it seems that some of the functions are accessed by index, and other are accessed by row numbers? I am confused. Can someone explain to me? What are the best practices? Are some functions using index to access values, and other are using row numbers? Have I misunderstood something? Should I always reset_index() as often I can? Or never do that?

EDIT: To recap: I manually merge some rows in functions so there will be gaps in  the indicies. In other functions I iterate over each row and do calculations. However, if I have reset the index I get other calculation results than if I don't reset the index. Why? That is my problem.

Comment: iloc should work no matter what the index labels are.  iloc (integer location) will retrieve rows based on their integer location in the index.

Answer (score 3):

`.loc[]` looks at index **labels**, which may or may not be integer-valued.

- If your index is `[0, 1, 3]` (a non-sequential integer index), `.loc[2]` won't find anything, because there is no index label `2`.
- Similarly, if your index is `['a', 'b', 'c']` (a non-integer index), `.loc[2]` will come up empty.

`.iloc[]` looks at index **positions**, which will always be integer-valued.

- If your index is `[0, 1, 3]`, `.loc[2]` will return the row corresponding to `3`.
- If your index is `['a', 'b', 'c']`, `.loc[2]` will return the row corresponding to `'c'`.

That's not a bug, that's just how those indexers are designed.  Whether one fits your purpose depends on the structure of your data and what you're trying to accomplish.  It's hard to make a recommendation without knowing more.

That said, it does sound like your code is getting kind of thorny.  Having to perform `reset_index()` in a bunch of different places and keep constant track of which row you're trying to update suggest that you may not be taking advantage of Pandas' ability to perform vector-based calculations across many rows and columns at once.  Maybe the task you want to accomplish makes this inevitable.  But it's worth taking some time to consider whether you can't vectorize some of what you're doing, so that you can apply it to the whole dataframe or a subset of the dataframe, rather than operating on individual cells one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know what you just explained, that loc() looks at labels, and iloc looks at indicies. 

I cannot vectorize the code, I need to look at each cell and do complicated calculations depending on lot of other conditions. I frequently merge several rows into one via some complicated conditions, and then I keep track of the rows that I have merged and delete them at the end of the function. But then the index gets messed up so I must reset it. All my indicies are the default numbers, I have not changed indicies to another column than the normal index column. I am confused.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem.  If you know that `.iloc` and `.loc` give different results and why, then you know why, in your words "if I have reset the index I get other calculation results than if I don't reset the index".  Maybe you can be more specific about the problem you're having and how the results you expect differ from the ones you're getting.